# Sql server join by group?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join, dataexplorer

I have this table :

```
id   |  type |      date    
 1   |    a  |   01/1/2012   
 2   |    b  |   01/1/2012
 3   |    b  |   01/2/2012   
 4   |    b  |   01/3/2012   
 5   |    a  |   01/5/2012   
 6   |    b  |   01/5/2012   
 7   |    b  |   01/9/2012   
 8   |    a  |   01/10/2012
```

The POV is *per date*. if 2 rows contains the same date    , so both will visible in the same line ( left join).

Same date can be shared by 2 rows max.

*so this situation can't be :*

```
 1   |    a  |   01/1/2012   
 2   |    b  |   01/1/2012
 3   |    a  |   01/1/2012
```

if in the same date there is group `a` and `b` show both of them in single line using left join

if in date there is only `a` group , show it as single line ( +null at the *right* side  )

if in date there is only b group , show it as single line ( +null at the *left* side   )

Desired result :

```
   Date         |typeA|typeB  |a'id|b'id
  01/1/2012     |  a  |  b    | 1  |  2
  01/2/2012     |     |  b    |    |  3
  01/3/2012     |     |  b    |    |  4
  01/5/2012     |   a |  b    | 5  |  6
  01/9/2012     |     |  b    |    |  7
  01/10/2012    |   a |       | 8  |
```

I know this suppose to be simple , but the main anchor of join here is the date.
The problem I've encountered is when I read line 1 , i search in the table all rows with the same date...fine. - its ok.

But when I read the second line , I do it also , and it yields the first row - which already was counted...

any help ?

here is the sql fiddle :

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/82605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
 select 
    [date],
    case when [a] IS null then null else 'a' end typea,
    case when [b] IS null then null else 'b' end typeb,
    a as aid,
    b as bid
 from yourtable src
 pivot  (max(id) for type in ([a],[b]))p
```

If you want to do it with joins..

```
select ISNULL(a.date, b.date), a.type,b.type, a.id,b.id
from
(select * from yourtable where type='a') a
    full outer join
(select * from yourtable where type='b') b  
    on a.date = b.date
```

Comment: Thanks.is there any _join_ solution ?

Comment: oh sh**  - how did you do that...?... you're great.

Comment: What was the trigger which cause you to think about full outer join ?

Comment: Oh really, there's no need :). I don't know why. I guess it was your mention of left and right.